# Why did two edits 37 seconds apart not get treated as one?

Tags: support, edits, comments, grace-period

I just made a pair of edits at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30677292/revisions.  I was surprised that I had to re-enter a reason, and then the review history shows that they were treated as independent edits, even though there was just 37 seconds between them.

Is this a catastrophe? No, it certainly isn't.  It's a minor issue.

But, is that expected behaviour, and if so why? (It used to be that two consecutive edits within 5 minutes would be treated as one, so there is some change of behaviour.) Did something else happen to make that appropriate for this edit?  Or is it a general regression?

Comment: Heh. My personal bet is, for once, not on caching but on load balancing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: It could be that. I used the same browser tab for both; I wasn't on different machines or using different browsers, browser windows or tabs.

Comment: Nope, I meant load balancing on the server side.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I assumed as much.  I was adding some extra circumstances that suggest that the problem was not client side.  There might have been a client-side explanation if I had used a different machine, or a different browser (Chrome vs Firefox, perhaps), or different browser windows, or different tabs in a single browser window.  So, while those might be excuses for a problem because of a change in the client, those excuses don't apply, which makes 'load balancing' in the SO supply chain (server side) more plausible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [relatively new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876) that breaks the "5 minute grace period" for an edit revision automatically when specific actions happen, such as a comment.

The exact conditions, per Shog9 from that link are:

> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677292/why-does-defining-main-with-no-return-type-compile-with-no-error#comment49416215_30677292) occurred at exactly 23:37:44 which was right in between your 2 edits are 23:37:31 and 23:38:08.  Because of that comment, your 2nd edit was treated as a new revision and not an edit within the grace period.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it.  It's the first time I've hit it, that's all.  On the whole, that makes sense.  Certainly, the problem of edited posts without revision history when there are substantive changes made was a problem.  I'm glad it's been fixed, and I'm mildly surprised I'd not encountered the new behaviour before.